# How can I record game audio with screen without using microphone?

Tags: video-recording, audio-recording

I found so many apps which can record screen on my android device.
Some of them can record audio and video at the same time, but only when I turned on the "Record with microphone" option.

That's not realy good, becouse the game sound can be a little bit noisy that way, so I need to record the game audio without using my microphone for best quality.

I would be grateful if the solution does not require a computer for audio recording.

My device is:
Sony Xperia Z2
Android version 5.1.1
Not rooted and can't root it becouse if I do, I lose my warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have been using the SCR Pro for game recording without using microphone.
Install the app, then you launch the app, there are 3 buttons, tap on the setting icon, scroll down to the Audio tab, tap source, tap System Audio Output (or Internal). And there you go. But I am not sure if that one requires root or not.